# How to save an error to Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am basically looking to save an error to a MySql database.

So If a query fails the error will be saved to a MySQL table?

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {}
else
{      
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO audit_hr_employees 
(tab, employee, error_type, user, result, other)
VALUES ('4a', '$employee', 'warning', '$user', 'Error', '$sql')";
}
```

As you can see from the above example I have tried adding `$sql` into the database however it does not show anything.

This is not a duplicate of the last link that has been posted.

Comment: You made the same mistake again

Comment: Who is upvoting this? I smell voter fraud

Comment: Where you execute `$sql1` query??and where you define `$sql`??

Comment: @JohnConde - It is not a duplicate? of the link you posted? Also i'm not sure how to see who has upvoted?

Comment: @saty - '$sql1 = "INSERT INTO audit_hr_employees'

Comment: Please display the results when you echo `sql1`.

Comment: No: You create a string with a query in it ___but you do not issue it to the database in a `$conn->query($sql1)`___

Comment: Also what happens if the error you are reporting is `there is no connection to the database` do you recursively fail to write a row to the database _from here to eternity_